# How can we get an alert when Designer workflow is suspended or terminated

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I need to create an alert(preferably configured mail) whenever my SharePoint designer workflow(2013) is suspended due to some error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to provide a snippet of your code or try at least to describe what have you done and what has been the output. That would help a lot understanding your problem and trying to find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to the Workflow History list in your site (it may be hidden from the Site Contents view, but you can always type in the URL directly `<<yourbasesiteurl>>/lists/Workflow%20History/`).
- Create a view on this list filtered where the Status column is not equal to "In progress", and is not equal to "Completed"
- Subscribe to [alerts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918#Pick_tab=SharePoint_Server_2010_-_2019) on this View

Comment: If this answer helped, please be sure to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)